# in EF does AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false enable Identity Resolution

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have seen that `.AsNoTracking` and `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false`  are basicaly equivalent but with a different scope. However there is a new option `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution`. So, like the title says, does does ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false affect Identity Resolution? using EF 7.0.